# How to make this function return 0 when the element is not found?

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm

I wrote a function in C that searches for an element `k` in an array `arr`(its sorted, all its elements are in descending order):

```
int search(int arr[], int start, int end, int k) {
    int mid = 0.5 * (start + end);
    if (k == arr[mid] || k == arr[start] || k == arr[end]) {
        return 1;
    } else
    if (k > arr[mid]) {
        end = mid;
        search(arr, start, end, k);
    } else {
        start = mid; 
        search(arr, start, end, k);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n, i, k;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int arr[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    scanf("%d", &k);
    if (search(arr, 0, n - 1, k) == 1)
        printf("1");
    else
        printf("0");
}
```

I want to make this return 0 whenever the element `k` does not exist in the array. I tried to add a `return 0` way at the bottom of the function. But my `printf` function then doesn't print 0. It does print 1 however. Can anyone help me understand what's going on here?

Comment: You need to start by adopting a conventional, readable coding style. If you write messy code like this you are on your own, don't expect others to read it.

Comment: @Lundin I'm sorry, let me fix that.

Comment: Well you didn't. Conventional code formatting would rather look along the lines of this: https://godbolt.org/z/37nd6hGqa. Brace placement and indention depth 2 or 4 spaces is subjective, the rest is not.

Comment: Are the elements of `arr` sorted? Otherwise you cannot apply the bisection search.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks very much, I didn't know this. I'm only a beginner.

Comment: @tshiono Yes, sorted in descending order. Edited.

Comment: Take a nice small example input and start debugging your code (even possible with pen and paper).

Comment: Returning 0/1 is pretty old fashioned. Use a bool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please make sure that the array is sorted.
Second is you need to *return* the value from the subsequent calls you are making.
Third is you need to take care of the range of search being done to actually bisect them and individually search in each half.

**Fixed Snippet:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int search(int arr[], int start, int end, int k) {
    if(start > end) return 0;
    int mid = 0.5 * (start + end);
    if (k == arr[mid]) return 1;
    else if (k > arr[mid]) return search(arr, start, mid - 1, k);
    return search(arr, mid + 1, end, k);
}

int compare( const void* a, const void* b)
{
     int int_a = * ( (int*) a );
     int int_b = * ( (int*) b );

     if ( int_a == int_b ) return 0;
     else if ( int_a < int_b ) return 1;
     else return -1;
}

int main() {
    int n, i, k;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int arr[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    scanf("%d", &k);
    // sort them to apply binary search unless you wish to insert only sorted values
    qsort( arr, n, sizeof(int), compare );
    if (search(arr, 0, n - 1, k) == 1)
        printf("1");
    else
        printf("0");
}
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/c/3xvg8wqny)